# What are the effective ways to repel mosquitoes without using commercial products?

Tags: pest-control

Are there any life hacks or natural ways of repelling mosquitoes without using commercial products which may contain harmful chemicals?

I've already tried few iPhone apps which generates supposedly mosquito-repelling frequencies, but they doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** There are some natural etheric/essential oils which have mosquito-repelling power. I know about:

- lavender oil
- citronella oil
- lemon eucalyptus oil
- soybean oil

The same fragrances may be in the form of candles, sticks or something else which is usually used for aroma therapy. But I prefer to use essential oil in aroma lamp with a small candle to warm the oil mixed with water, like the one on the picture:

[image]

There are electric aroma lamps but I have no experience with them.

**2.** Another thing you can try is to put some mosquito-repelling plants in you house or around it. Some of them are:

- Tan­sies
- Marigolds
- Cat­nip
- Thai Lemon Grass
- Cit­ronella Grass
- Gar­lic
- Horsemint
- Ageratum

An you can find some other plants with repelling action.

Comment: Also Rosemary, as twig thrown into the fire repels insects.

Answer (score 6):

Mosquitoes are slow flyers.  Use a fan to repel them out of an area. See [Using Wind to Repel Mosquitoes](http://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/deeta.html)

Keep covered up.  Wear loose fitting clothing, long pants and long sleeves.  Tuck the pants in your socks.  Wear a hat.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of mosquitoes using strong-smelling plants, such as citronella, eucalyptus, mint, lemon, and tansy.
If you want to find more hints on how to repel mosquitoes check out [getting rid of mosquitoes naturally review](https://topmosquitokiller.com/getting-rid-of-mosquitoes-naturally-)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across these formulas for yard mosquito repellent sprays on Instagram.

> Mosquito time! Use that sugar you can't eat! Here's how:
>
> Have you noticed the Mosquitoes are already out! Here is a homemade trap to help keep you and the kiddos from being a blood donor!!! HOMEMADE MOSQUITO TRAP:
>
> - Items needed:
> - 1 cup of water
> - 1/4 cup of brown sugar
> - 1 gram of yeast
> - One empty Two-liter bottle
>
> HOW:
>
> 1. Cut the plastic bottle in half.
> 2. Mix brown sugar with hot water. Let cool. When cold, pour in the bottom half of the bottle.
> 3. Add the yeast. No need to mix. It creates carbon dioxide, which attracts mosquitoes.
> 4. Place the funnel part, upside down, into the other half of the bottle, taping them together if desired.
> 5. Wrap the bottle with something black, leaving the top uncovered, and place it outside in an area away from your normal gathering area. (Mosquitoes are also drawn to the color black.) Change the solution every two weeks for continuous control.

[Source image from Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK3oR.jpg)

---

> MOSQUITO YARD SPRAY
>
> - Big bottle Blue cheap mouthwash
> - 3 cups of Epsom salt
> - 3 stale 12 oz cheap beer
>
> Mix those three ingredients together until salt is dissolved.
>
> Spray anywhere you sit outside, around pools; will not harm plants or flowers... Mosquitoes gone from that area for approx. 80 days. I spray my deck all around my sitting areas twice a summer. Go out and sit in underwear all time at nite and never get bit .. They leave that area you spray and will not come back.. Been using this mixture last 15 years.. It works.. Heard about this on a Paul Harvey segment years ago, that's how I was informed about it.
>
> And it works well. All my friends that have tried it and can't believe it works.
>   The stronger you mix the longer it last.
>   Mosquitoes and bugs hate it. 
>   Has a nice mint smell...

[Source image from Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6pwq.jpg)

I cannot say whether either of these are effective or not.

Comment: @AllisonC Thank you for transcribing these! I made some further edits myself.

Comment: You're quite welcome; you may wish to add a note about improving the formatting and spelling on both. I stuck to a direct transcription, since they're quotes.

Comment: Perhaps these should have been separate answers? They both cover a large area, but only one is a yard spray.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I wanted to ping you: Not sure the migration of the antenna question was a good choice. Reads like a clear “how to”, which would be explicitly off-topic. Just a lowly user here, not a mod, so I’ll just cast a vote.

Comment: @Stephie There seems to be a contradiction in the [help sections](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour). But thanks.